# Python: send email to multiple addresses

Tags: python, email, smtp

I have four python functions that I am using to send mail.  If the program does one thing, it mails a set of results to a multiple recipients, if it does another thing, a separate function mails the results to one recipient.

```
def smail(to,sub,body):
    addr_from = 'alert@example.com'
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = addr_from
    msg['To'] = to
    msg['Subject'] = sub
    msg.attach(body)
    s = smtplib.SMTP('webmail.example.com')
    s.sendmail(addr_from, [to], msg.as_string())
    s.quit()

def email_format2(results):
    text = ""
    text += 'The following applications in <environment> are non-compliant\n'
    text += '<br>'
    text += 'Here are there names and locations.  Please inform the developer.'
    text += '<br>'
    text += '<br>'
    table = pd.DataFrame.from_records(results)
    table_str = table.to_html()
    text += "%s" % table_str
    return text

def mail_results_aq(results):
    body = email_format2(results)
    msg = MIMEText(body, 'html')
    sub = "Placeholder subject"
    to = 'email1@example.com, email2@example.com, email3@example.com'
    smail(to, sub, msg)

def mail_results_prd(results):
    body = email_format2(results)
    msg = MIMEText(body, 'html')
    sub = "Placeholder subject"
    to = 'email4@example.com'
    smail(to, sub, msg)
```

The mail_results_aq function will only email results to the first recipient (email1@example.com).

In other questions similar to this one, I've seen a the recipients being entered into a list i.e

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.uk.xensource.com')
s.set_debuglevel(1)
msg = MIMEText("""body""")
sender = 'me@example.com'
recipients = ['john.doe@example.com', 'john.smith@example.co.uk']
msg['Subject'] = "subject line"
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)
s.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
```

However, this use case only seems to work when used in the same function.  How can I implement this feature across the four functions I have above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't really understand why it is a problem to change this line `s.sendmail(addr_from, [to], msg.as_string())` to `s.sendmail(addr_from, to.split(", "), msg.as_string())`

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you.